# How to indicate the language in the Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Just like you visit `maps.google.com.tw` or `maps.google.co.kr` or `maps.google.co.jp`, you can see their own language shown on every country. Is there any property that I can use in Google Maps API to dynamically set google maps using specific language to display?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

In Google Maps API v3, add "language" attribute to script tag. For example, the following will set map to display Russian in location names and navigation buttons:

```
<script 
  src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;language=ru-RU"      
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Is there no way to set the language after the map has been loaded, in Javascript?

Comment: Still finding the way to change language dynamically or API key as well. See no way except manual script reconnection.

Answer (score 15):

In Google Maps v3, you can use the "language" parameter:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;language=en"></script>
```

Language codes list: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport

More info: http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2009/10/maps-api-v3-now-speaks-your-language.html

Answer (score 7):

**For the V2 Maps API:**

You can add an optional `hl` parameter to the `<script>` tag when including the Google Maps API, specifying the domain language to use, as in the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <title>Localization of the Google Maps API</title> 
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&sensor=false&hl=ko"
            type="text/javascript"></script> 
  </head> 
  <body onunload="GUnload()"> 

    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
       var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
       map.setCenter(new GLatLng(36.48, 128.00), 7);
       map.setUIToDefault();
    </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Screenshot:

[image: Localization of the Google Maps API]

You may also want to check out the following resources for further reading:

- [Supported list of domain languages](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport)
- [Localization of the Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/#Localization)

Comment: Thanks for the quick and accurate response.

Comment: After I test, in v3, language "hl" parameter doesn't support yet.

Answer (score 1):

language code is  IETF language code:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag

```
<script 
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;language=ru-RU"      
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```