# How to indicate Hindi language in the Google Maps API? do anyone suggest me the code for hindi language for map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

As I know we can set language in map by giving the language parameter in the `<script src>` tag. i.e

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&language=jp"></script>
```

Where do I get the complete list of language code? Basically I am looking language code for the **HINDI** language

Comment: have you even googled it?!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to indicate the language in the Google Maps API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662889/how-to-indicate-the-language-in-the-google-maps-api)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure a bit of Googling would have helped.
Here you go:
https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=p9pdwsai2hDMsLkXsoM05KQ&gid=1

So Hindi is hi

Comment: Thanks carsten, I want all country name should appear in the hindi language.

Comment: The language parameter is the only thing that you can adjust in the API - there is nothing else that can be adjusted. According to the documentation it should modify the tags and also the location names so it should work.